# How to add Smooth CSS drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I managed to create a menu with drop-down-menu (sub menu) using CSS. But I can't able to add smooth drop down-menu effect to my coding. I tried to add -moz-transition and more. I didn't know where to add those transition to make my normal drop-down-menu as smooth drop down-menu effect.

Below is my HTML coding

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #cssmenu ul,
    #cssmenu li,
    #cssmenu span,
    #cssmenu a {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu {
      height: 49px;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
      background: #fefefe;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefefe), color-stop(100%, #eee9f0));
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #eee9f0 100%);
      border-bottom: 2px solid #db000b;
      width: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu:after,
    #cssmenu ul:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    #cssmenu a {
      background: #fefefe;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefefe), color-stop(100%, #ececec));
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #ececec 100%);
      color: #000;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 49px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul {
      float: left;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li {
      float: left;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
      color: #000;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid #db000b;
      margin-left: -10px;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
      border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid #db000b;
      margin-left: -10px;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      background: #ececec;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ececec), color-stop(100%, #ffeeff ef));
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
      background: #ececec;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ececec), color-stop(100%, #ffeeff ef));
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(top, #ececec 0%, #ffeeff ef 100%);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub {
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
      display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub ul {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
      *margin-bottom: -1px;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
      background: #db000b;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0f1b;
      filter: none;
      font-size: 11px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 120%;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
      background: #a80008;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
      display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
      background: #a80008;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0f1b;
    }
    #cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
      background: #8f0007;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: You can use [twitter bootstrap][1] who provide a very nice drop down menu


  [1]: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote 'smooth CSS menu' you meant without javascript and only CSS ?

If so, use css level 3 transition.

```
#cssmenu ul ul { 
    /* this will apply to inner UL, adapt to your desired selector */
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

If it is not working for your context, perhaps it is because there is no 'height to your inner UL element.

```
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  height:auto; /* add this */
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height:0; /* add this */
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

For more about the topic for a cross-browser solution, search the net for **css transition generator**

Comment: I tried to add the above to my CSS but the output is same as earlier

Comment: I thought you'd figure it out by yourself, i edited my answer to explain why it is not working. I'll be please to help you a little more if you provide a working context such has jsFiddle.

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle live example http://jsfiddle.net/E4Q4b/1/ I updated my CSS with yours. But I can't get the desired output. Kindly sort out my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using something a little more extensive, such as jQuery, to give your desired effect. Here's a link to the 'accordion' effect that sounds like something you're going for. The layout of the accordion menu is completely adjustable - so don't worry if you don't like the design of the default layout.

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default

Adding jQuery to your webpage takes about 30 seconds, but gives you an eternity of useful additions, animations, and interactive content manipulation for your page!

Answer (score 0):

u can use jquery for easing effects for your dropdwon menu here is one example

http://devsnippets.com/article/slick-drop-down-menu-with-easing-effect-using-jquery-css.html

Answer (score 0):

I use this
http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-drop-down-menu

This menu is created only in CSS3 which is inspired from this post on Forrst! This consists of a nested ul structure to create the second level of the menu which is initially hidden with it's opacity set to 0. When the link is hovered, the respective ul shows up and slides down. This is achieved by setting its opacity to 1 and changing it's top offset when it's hovered in conjuction with the CSS3 transitions to animate the process smoothly.

Check out the code and play with it as much as you like :)

Comment: Greetings user3065369. You are invited to take the tour about questions and answers. You will find usefull tips about Not to post a link that looks more like an 'ad' than an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/tour